# how to get new access token with auth0 and refresh token on bitbucket

Tags: python, bitbucket, access-token, auth0, refresh-token

I'm trying to get a new access token using the refresh token using Auth0 on provider Bitbucket.  According to Bitbucket documentation, the refresh token along client client_id and secret is used to get a new access token.

```
curl -X POST -u "client_id:secret"
      https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token \
      -d grant_type=refresh_token -d refresh_token={refresh_token}
```

But it seems that I'm supposed to use Auth0 as a proxy for this.  It says in Auth0 documenttation to use the refresh token (user specific) along with my Auth0 domain and Auth0 client id.  It seems a bit strange to mix my Auth0 credentials with a refresh token for a Bitbucket user.

https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/concepts/idp-access-tokens?_ga=2.56840622.505323938.1583403242-2086121138.1583403242#renew-tokens

This is my flow:

## (1) set AUTH0 client info

- set auth0 client id
- set auth0 client secret
- set auth0 domain
- retrieve auth0 client token

## (2) get initial user info

get user info at endpoint:

```
https://<auth0_domain>.auth0.com/api/v2/users/<user_id>
```

- this will contain an access token for the user
- this will also contain a refresh token for the "user" not the AUTH0 client (I assume?)

## (3) try to get access token from refresh token

use the refresh token to get an access token here:

```
https://<auth0_domain>.auth0.com/oauth/token
```

notably, the refresh token is for the user, but the client info is from the AUTH0 client - doesn't make sense to me.  this fails with this error.

```
{u'error_description': u'Unauthorized', u'error': u'access_denied'}
```

It fails on this essentially:

```
payload = { "client_id": self.auth0_client_id,
                            "client_secret": self.auth0_client_secret,
                            "refresh_token": kwargs["refresh_token"].decode("utf-8"),
                            "grant_type": "refresh_token" }

        _endpt = 'https://{}.auth0.com/oauth/token'.format(self.auth0_domain)
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

        req = requests.post(_endpt,
                            data=json.dumps(payload),
                            headers=headers)
```

Below is the entire code from my class in python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

    import json
    import os
    import requests
    import logging

    class Auth0Client(object):

        def __init__(self,**kwargs):

            self.classname = "Auth0Client"
            self.logger.logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

            # (1) set AUTH0 client info

            self.auth0_client_id = os.environ["AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"]
            self.auth0_client_secret = os.environ["AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET"]
            self.auth0_domain = os.environ["AUTH0_DOMAIN"]
            self._set_auth0_client_token()

        def _set_auth0_client_token(self):

            payload = { "client_id": self.auth0_client_id,
                        "client_secret": self.auth0_client_secret,
                        "audience": "https://{}.auth0.com/api/v2/".format(self.auth0_domain),
                        "grant_type": "client_credentials" }

            api_endpoint = 'https://{}.auth0.com/oauth/token'.format(self.auth0_domain)

            req = requests.post(api_endpoint,
                                data=json.dumps(payload),
                                headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})

            self.auth0_client_token = req.json()["access_token"].decode("utf-8")

        def _get_userinfo_frm_auth0(self,user):

            endpoint = "https://{}.auth0.com/api/v2/users/{}".format(self.auth0_domain,user)
            headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % self.auth0_client_token}
            req = requests.get(endpoint,headers=headers)

            return req.json()

        def _get_user_access_token_with_refresh(self,**kwargs):

            payload = { "client_id": self.auth0_client_id,
                        "client_secret": self.auth0_client_secret,
                        "refresh_token": kwargs["refresh_token"].decode("utf-8"),
                        "grant_type": "refresh_token" }

            _endpt = 'https://{}.auth0.com/oauth/token'.format(self.auth0_domain)
            headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

            req = requests.post(_endpt,
                                data=json.dumps(payload),
                                headers=headers)

            return req.json()["access_token"].decode("utf-8")

        def get_user_access_token(self,user):

            # (2) get initial user info
            user_info = self._get_userinfo_frm_auth0(user)

            if str(user_info["identities"][0]["provider"]) == "bitbucket":
                # (3) try to get access token from refresh token
                user_token = self._get_user_access_token_with_refresh(user=user,**user_info["identities"][0])
            else:
                user_token = user_info["identities"][0]["access_token"].decode("utf-8")

            return user_token
```

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out with the help from the auth0 community.  i posted the solution and flow here if anything needs it:

https://github.com/gear2000/auth0-bitbucket